# How can I encrypt a string in the shell?

Tags: linux, encryption

Can I encrypt a message (string) using a public key at the command prompt? Also, how can I decrypt the result afterwards?

Answer (score 38):

Another option is `openssl`:

```
# generate a 2048-bit RSA key and store it in key.txt
openssl genrsa -out key.txt 2048

# encrypt "hello world" using the RSA key in key.txt
echo "hello world" | openssl rsautl -inkey key.txt -encrypt >output.bin

# decrypt the message and output to stdout
openssl rsautl -inkey key.txt -decrypt <output.bin
```

Comment: +1 for openssl since it's more commonly installed than gpg is

Comment: This is perfect - works on Mac, Alpine, anything... good work!

Comment: yeah how about an example not using a file but an argument?

Comment: Only works for ~240 bytes of data, which many 'messages' exceed, and uses pkcs1-v1_5 which if adversary can get you to decrypt chosen ciphertexts allow Bleichenbacker attack.

Answer (score 14):

If you have `gpg` installed, this is an industrial-strength encryption method.

```
gpg --encrypt -r recipient@example.com >tempfile
```

Type data at the console and press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to end the text. This will give you encrypted data in `tempfile`. To decrypt:

```
gpg --decrypt <tempfile
```

You will need the passphrase for `recipient@example.com` to decrypt the message.

Comment: ok, so if the passphrase needs to be inputted interactively, how to do it non-interactively? *How do this non-interactively?*

Comment: `gpg --encrypt -r recipient@example.com >tempfile

gpg: error retrieving 'recipient@example.com' via WKD: No data
gpg: recipient@example.com: skipped: No data
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No data
` ( I am on a mac)

Answer (score 9):

1. Generate a private/public key pair

   ```
   $ openssl genrsa -out rsa_key.pri 2048; openssl rsa -in rsa_key.pri -out rsa_key.pub -outform PEM -pubout
   ```
2. Encrypt the string using public key, and store in a file

   ```
   $ echo "stockexchange.com" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey rsa_key.pub -pubin -out secret.dat
   ```
3. Un-encrypt using private key

   ```
   $ string=`openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey rsa_key.pri -in secret.dat `; echo $string
   stockexchange.com
   ```

Comment: This adds almost nothing to the 8-year-earlier answer, and has the same problems.

Answer (score 5):

[man crypt(1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/crypt-1.html)

**note:**

> crypt implements a one-rotor machine
>   designed along the lines of the German
>   Enigma, but with a 256-element rotor.
>   Methods of attack on such machines are
>   widely known, thus crypt provides
>   minimal security.

But it's OK for demonstration purposes.

Comment: "Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 Information Library"